# Nested Lambda in Scheme?

Tags: lambda, nested, scheme, racket, evaluation

> Evaluate `(((lambda(x y) (lambda (x) (* x y))) 5 6) 10)` in Scheme.

I am not sure how to do this actually!

```
((lambda (x y) (+ x x y)) 3 5)
```

Is fairly simple. Here x=3, y=5.

But in this the body is: `(lambda (x) (* x y))) 5 6)` and the parameter is `10`?

So we evaluate separately? As in `(lambda (x) (* x y))) 5 6) = (* 5 y)` And then `(((lambda(x y) (lambda (x) (* x y))) 5 6) 10) = (((lambda (x y) (* 5 y) 10))`

But how can that be evaluated?

Comment: Please don't completely change your question. That invalidates the answers that people have taken time to write. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if you rename the parameter in the inner lambda:

```
(((lambda (x y) (lambda (z) (* z y))) 5 6) 10)
```

The outer lambda is applied to 5 and 6:

```
((lambda (x y) (lambda (z) (* z y))) 5 6)
```

This evaluates to

```
(lambda (z) (* z 6))
```

since `y`is bound to `6`.
Note that `x` from the outer lambda (which is bound to `5`) is never used.

This function is then applied

```
((lambda (z) (* z 6)) 10)
```

which yields `60`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(((lambda (x y) (lambda (x) (* x y))) 5 6) 10)
```

is

```
(  (  (lambda (x y) 
         (lambda (x) (* x y))
         )
      5 
      6) 
   10)
```

is

[image]

See? The inner lambda is returned as a *value*, as result of the application of the outer lambda to arguments 5 and 6. The new value is *enclosed* in its defining environment, where `x=5` and `y=6` -- such lambda is otherwise known as *closure*:

[image]

It is then applied to 10:

```
(((lambda (x y) (lambda (x) (* x y))) 5 6) 10)

= ( (let ((x 5)
          (y 6))
       (lambda (x) (* x y)))
    10)

= (let ((x 5)
        (y 6))
     ( (lambda (x) (* x y))
       10))

= (let ((x 5)
        (y 6))
      (let ((x 10))
          (* x y)))

=         (* 10 6)

=         60
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with `(lambda(x y) (lambda (x) (* x y)))`. This is a function expression that takes two parameters and returns another function expression. For convenience, I will refer to the entire expression as `f`.

Now consider `(f 5 6)`. This returns another lambda, `(lambda (x) (* x y)`, with y bound to the value passed in. However, the inner `x` parameter shadows the outer one, so the result is `(f 5 6) = (lambda (x) (* x 6)`.

From here, we can directly evaluate `((lambda (x) (* x 6)) 10)`. This yields a final result of `60`.

Comment: No. The 10 is applied to the result of ((lambda (x y) ... ) 5 6). Look carefully at the parentheses (or use an editor that can show you matching parens).